# How to know and prevent an error with terminal commands from python?

Tags: python, macos, darwin

Making a program which can open apps upon listening to commands. The app name is stored in variable 'a'. And then opened with the following line:

```
os.system("open /Applications/" + a + ".app")
```

But sometimes it is possible that 'a' does not exist on the system, say 'music' for which the console prints:

```
The file /Applications/music.app does not exist.
```

And the python code stops entirely.

How can I know that the console gave this error and prevent the program from stopping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) is more powerful than `os.system`, the stdout and stderr of subprocess can be ignored with subprocess

```py
import subprocess
res=subprocess.run(["open", "/Applications/" + a + ".app"])
print(res.returncode)
```

use `res.returncode` to get the execute result(none zero value shows that the sub process has encountered errors).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use the `try`/`except` commands to handle errors in python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html.